# Elements Must Only Use Allowed ARIA Attributes How to Fix?

Tags: wordpress, web, accessibility, wai-aria

**i know nothing about code. I did a website performance checker and it came back with a few things to fix my website, only problem is I have no clue what it is and would love help. This way i can also learn it and be prepared for next time something like this happens. i have included some images of the issue, but here are also the issues typed out:**

Elements Must Only Use Allowed ARIA Attributes
Fix any of the following: ARIA attribute is not allowed: aria-selected="false"2

ARIA Hidden Element Must Not Contain Focusable Elements
Fix all of the following: Focusable content should be disabled or be removed from the DOM1
Fix all of the following: Focusable content should be disabled or be removed from the DOM3

ARIA Input Fields Must Have An Accessible Name
Fix any of the following: aria-label attribute does not exist or is empty aria-labelledby attribute does not exist, references elements that do not exist or references elements that are empty Element has no title attribute

Certain ARIA Roles Must Contain Particular Children
Fix any of the following: Required ARIA child role not present: tab

im not even sure where to begin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doDu9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Accessible Rich Internet Applications ([ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)) is a suite of standards to support assistive technology in browsers, like text-to-speech screen readers, support for people with unconventional dexterity abilities, and those sorts of things. ARIA is good because accessibility is good.

The performance checker you used is testing your website against some rules to see if you've implemented ARIA perfectly. Like almost every other web site on the planet, you haven't done it exactly perfectly. If I were you I would not worry too much about the complaints you showed us, unless you have many visitors who need assistive technology and this is impeding their use of your site.

Fixing these detailed issues is up to the developer of your theme and maybe some plugins. As a web publisher the single biggest accessibility boost YOU can offer is putting "alt text" describing every photo and image on your site.

If you're worried about this you might put a "tell us about your problem" form somewhere on your site and put a link in a widget asking visitors to tell you about accessibility issues.

And you can let your plugin developer know.